Is there a better way to fetch data for multiple pages in nuxt 3?
Right now I have two layouts that are used for my pages. One with authentication (default.vue) and one without. There is one initial request that is called in default.vue and its data is then provided to all other components.
<script setup lang="ts">

 const isPending = ref(true)

 const allData = await loadData()
 isPending.value = false
 provide('allData', allData)

</script>

<template>
  <client-only>
    <LoadingAnimation v-if="isPending" class="bg-dark"/>
  </client-only>
  <div v-if="!isPending" id="app">
    <AppHeader />
      <slot />
    <AppFooter />
  </div>
</template>

This works with one limitation -> the loading animation is not visible. Instead just white html page or when routing the routing is stopped until request is resolved.
I tried moving the loadData() into the onBeforeMount() hook.
<script setup lang="ts">
const allData = ref()
provide('allData', allData)
const isPending = ref(true)

onBeforeMount(() => {
 isPending.value = true
 allData.value = await loadData()
 isPending.value = false

})

</script>

Then the loading animation works. But somehow my pages will be mounted before the request in default.vue layout will be resolved -> the injected allData variable is undefined. At some pages I need that data even before the beforeMounted hook.
Is there a better way to fetch and provide data for multiple pages?
Why are my components that use the default.vue layout mounted before layout is resolved?

This "somehow" is the way vue works. Don't use the second snippet if you rely on this data on the first render. I'd suggest to check first https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense . The question is too unspecific, there's no "better" way. If you try to address the problem with loading animation then ask about this, the answer will be different. It's await in setup that prevents the component from being rendered until setup is complete. Move loader animation to a parent
